# Several ids sent into "in"?

Tags: sql

I would like something like this.

```
select car.name
from car
where 
(1 AND 2) IN (Select c.ConfigItemId from Contract c where c.ContractId = 
Car.ContractId)
```

It looks simple enough but I have not found a solution.
The only thing I have found is to have one line for each id to be matched.

```
" AND (1) IN (Select c.ConfigItemId from Contract c where c.ContractId = 
Car.ContractId)"
 AND (2) IN (Select c.ConfigItemId from Contract c where c.ContractId = 
Car.ContractId)"
```

What is the best way to do this?

I think I need to clarify this.
I want it to be necessary for all the values I send in "i,2" to exist in the contract.configid.

Comment: Switch from IN to EXISTS.

Comment: Instead of subquery, use inner join and use where clause `where car.contractid in ('1','2')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple exists:

```
select  car.name
from    car
where   EXISTS (
                    SELECT  NULL
                    FROM    Contract c 
                    WHERE   c.ContractId = Car.ContractId
                        AND c.ConfigItemId IN (1, 2)
                    GROUP BY c.ContractId
                    HAVING   COUNT(distinct c.ConfigItemId) > 1
                )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it by `INNER JOIN` and `IN`

```
select car.name from car
INNER JOIN Contract as c on c.ContractId = Car.ContractId
where c.ConfigItemId IN (1,2)
GROUP BY c.ContractId
HAVING COUNT(distinct c.ConfigItemId) > 1
```

Comment: But I only want it to show up if ALL of the values 1,2 are in the c.configitem

Comment: So, what I understand, ConfigItemId for any car which have 1 & 2 both then only it should return record

Answer (score 1):

EXISTS would be better from a performance perspective, but something like this might work.

```
select car.name from car
join Contract c on c.ContractId = car.ContractId
where c.ConfigItemId in (1,2)
```